# How to count rows matching interrelated conditions?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have table that looks like this:

```
TripID    | Name | State  
    1     | John |  OH       
    2     | John |  OH  
    3     | John |  CA  
    4     | John |  OH  
    1     | Mike |  CA  
    2     | Mike |  CA  
    3     | Mike |  OH
```

I'd like to count the people who travelled to OH first followed by CA.

In the above case it'd be John only so the answer should be 1.

So I want to know how can we set a certain order in SQL filtering to filter the result?

Comment: first is arbitrary if you don't have a column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: Hey @vkp can you be more specific here please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have misunderstood your question perhaps, but if you're asking about:

> how many people travelled to OH first and then to CA.

(The sketch of) the query could be as follows:

```
scala> trips.show
+------+----+-----+
|tripid|name|state|
+------+----+-----+
|     1|John|   OH|
|     2|John|   OH|
|     3|John|   CA|
|     4|John|   OH|
|     1|Mike|   CA|
|     2|Mike|   CA|
|     3|Mike|   OH|
+------+----+-----+

scala> trips.orderBy("name", "tripid").groupBy("name").agg(collect_list("state")).show
+----+-------------------+
|name|collect_list(state)|
+----+-------------------+
|John|   [OH, OH, CA, OH]|
|Mike|       [CA, CA, OH]|
+----+-------------------+
```

As I see it now, you'd have two options:

1. (hard) Write a user-defined aggregate function (UDAF) that would do the aggregation (and would replace `collect_list` with a itinerary that'd contain distinct states).
2. (easier) Write a user-defined function (UDF) that would do a similar job as the UDAF above (but after `collect_list` have collected the values).
3. (easy) Use [functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) (like `explode` and/or `window`)

Let's do the easy solution (not necessarily the most effective!).

It turns out that the `groupBy` earlier is not really necessary (!) You can handle it using window aggregation alone (used twice).

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val byName = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("tripid")

val distinctStates = trips.withColumn("rank", rank over byName).dropDuplicates("name", "state").orderBy("name", "rank")

scala> distinctStates.show
+------+----+-----+----+
|tripid|name|state|rank|
+------+----+-----+----+
|     1|John|   OH|   1|
|     3|John|   CA|   3|
|     1|Mike|   CA|   1|
|     3|Mike|   OH|   3|
+------+----+-----+----+

// rank again but this time use the pre-calculated distinctStates dataset
val distinctStatesRanked = distinctStates.withColumn("rank", rank over byName).orderBy("name", "rank")

scala> distinctStatesRanked.show
+------+----+-----+----+
|tripid|name|state|rank|
+------+----+-----+----+
|     1|John|   OH|   1|
|     3|John|   CA|   2|
|     1|Mike|   CA|   1|
|     3|Mike|   OH|   2|
+------+----+-----+----+

val left = distinctStatesRanked.filter($"state" === "OH").filter($"rank" === 1)
val right = distinctStatesRanked.filter($"state" === "CA").filter($"rank" === 2)
scala> left.join(right, "name").show
+----+------+-----+----+------+-----+----+
|name|tripid|state|rank|tripid|state|rank|
+----+------+-----+----+------+-----+----+
|John|     1|   OH|   1|     3|   CA|   2|
+----+------+-----+----+------+-----+----+
```